# Kotlin does not allow charAt

Tags: java, kotlin

Why java compiles when kotlin not? And how to invoke `charAt` in kotlin?

Java:

```java
import java.nio.CharBuffer;

public class Test {
    public static void test() {
        CharBuffer buffer = CharBuffer.wrap("asd");
        buffer.charAt(0);
    }
}
```

Kotlin:

```java
import java.nio.CharBuffer

class TestKotlin {
    fun test() {
        val buffer = CharBuffer.wrap("asd")
        buffer.charAt(0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am theorizing from looking at [this old issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10151) that the Kotlin developers at one time accidentally treated `CharBuffer.charAt()` and `CharBuffer.get()` as equivalent and hid the `charAt()` method in Kotlin and mapped it to `get()`. They might have done this in an effort to promote the use of array-access syntax (brackets) and avoid supposed redundancy.

And perhaps later when the above issue was fixed, they missed unhiding the method.

`buffer.charAt(i)` would be `buffer[buffer.position() + i]` in Kotlin. You could write an extension function so you can continue to use it:

```
fun CharBuffer.charAt(index: Int) = this[position() + index]
```

The error message if you choose an out-of-bounds index will be slightly less informative than the one in the original method.

Maybe someone should open an issue on YouTrack for this...